# WordPress Categories Menu that is updated dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress

So I set up a WordPress Menu by adding all available categories. The menu works fine.

Here is how I set it up in WordPress:

[image]

This results in an unordered menu:

```
<ul>
   <li>Link 1</li>
   <li>Link 2</li>
   <li>Link 3
     <ul>
       <li>Link A</li>
       <li>Link B</li>
       <li>Link C</li>
       ...
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that I want this menu to be updated automatically/dynamically when a new Category/Subcategory is added. I can't seem to find any option in WordPress that could make this menu truly dynamic. Any idea how this can be accomplished rather than updating the menu all the time whenever a new category is added?

Comment: Can you share your piece of code. so, it's easy to debug.

Comment: @VimalUsadadiya Just updated my question. Basically, I want this menu to be dynamically updated if a category is added or removed.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/automatically-hierarchic-categories-in-menu/

Check this plugin. I think it will help you for your requirement.